# Insert the record in Type Record and extract the data from Type

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I want to insert the data into Type and want to extract the same in the procedure. its showing the table view doesn't exist even i have created the type with same name which i am using to insert the data. Please suggest.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
FACTORYID       VARCHAR2(200);
TYPE FACTORY_INFORMATION
    IS   RECORD
        (FACTORYID             VARCHAR2(1000),
         BILLINGDAY            VARCHAR2(1000),
         DUE_DAY               VARCHAR2(1000),
         FACTORYNAME           VARCHAR2(1000)
        );

    TYPE TT_FACTORY_INFORMATION   IS TABLE OF FACTORY_INFORMATION INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    FACTORY_INFO TT_FACTORY_INFORMATION;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO FACTORY_INFO (
SELECT 11,
       25,
       20,
       'xyz'
       FROM dual);
);

SELECT FACTORY_INFO INTO FACTORYID FROM FACTORY_INFO;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FACTORYID);
END;
```

Getting the below error.

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 16, column 13:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 16, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 23, column 41:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 23, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Read what it says. A **table** doesn't exist, not **type**.

Comment: yes that's why i want to know what is not exist as Type name alias with FACTORY_INFO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FACTORY_INFO is a PL/SQL variable not a table. So you can't use it as target for a SQL INSERT statement.

Likewise, because FACTORY_INFORMATION is a PL/SQL record type you can't select from it in SQL (not even using a `table()` function). You need to use PL/SQL collection operations.

You can do this:

```
DECLARE
  FACTORYID       VARCHAR2(200);
  TYPE FACTORY_INFORMATION
    IS   RECORD
        (FACTORYID             VARCHAR2(1000),
         BILLINGDAY            VARCHAR2(1000),
         DUE_DAY               VARCHAR2(1000),
         FACTORYNAME           VARCHAR2(1000)
        );

    TYPE TT_FACTORY_INFORMATION   IS TABLE OF FACTORY_INFORMATION INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    FACTORY_INFO TT_FACTORY_INFORMATION;

BEGIN
  SELECT 11,
         25,
         20,
         'xyz'
  bulk collect into FACTORY_INFO
  FROM dual;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FACTORY_INFO(1).FACTORYID);

END;
/
```

There is an entire chapter of the Oracle PL/SQL Reference devoted to Records and Collections, with plenty of examples of how to use them. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7115C8B6-62F9-496D-BEC3-F7441DFE148A)

Comment: Actually my requirment is to store the data in table in loop and want to featch the in same table in loop and want to store new values in every loop cycle so is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Of course there is. The documentation covers that scenario. However, if you would like an answer more focused on your need please **edit your question** to explain exactly what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: What you want to change my question.

Comment: I've answered the question you asked. But it seems you didn't find this helpful: if that is the case you need to **revise your question** to explain what it is you're really trying to achieve